# expected type-specifier before '...' token

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mingw

```
expected type-specifier before '...' token
```

This is the code

```
template< typename T, int t_nFixedBytes = 128, class Allocator = CCRTAllocator >
class CTempBuffer
{
public:
    CTempBuffer() throw() :
        m_p( NULL )
    {
    }
    CTempBuffer( size_t nElements )   throw( ... ) : <---ERROR HERE
        m_p( NULL )
    {
        Allocate( nElements );
    }
...
}
```

Now if i get rid of the throw(...) in the above statement this error is resolved.Any suggestions on why Mingw doesnt like `throw(...)` here ?

Comment: Simplest solution: skip CTempBuffer and just use std::vector instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `throw(...)` is not standard c++ syntax, but a MSVC++ specific extension. It just means that this function can throw any exception, which is equivalent to having no exception specification at all, so you can safely remove it.